# Autostart option plupload 1.5.6

Tags: file, upload, plupload, jscript, autostart

This question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227210/autostart-option-plupload-1-4-3-2) and [here](http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=90). But with version 1.5.6 placing init() before FilesAdded(...) makes it totally unresponsive. As well autostart uploading does not start at all either way.

```
var csvUploader = new function() {
var self = this;
self.init = function() {
    var uploader = new plupload.Uploader(
        {
            runtimes: 'html4',
            url: 'http://localhost:5073/Document/Upload',
            browse_button: 'uploadCsvButton',
            max_file_size: '100mb',
            chunk_size: '1mb',
            unique_names: true,
            filters: [{ title: "CSV files", extensions: "csv" }]
        });

    /* postion 1:  uploader.init(); /**/

    uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
        setTimeout(function () { up.start(); }, 500);
    });

    uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file) {
        // do some stuff here...
    });

    /*position 2: */ uploader.init(); /**/

}; // self.init

}; // NS:csvUploader
```

initalization of this module:

```
csvUploader.init();
```

So experienced colleagues what is wrong here? Modular pattern or smth else? As init() is in position 2 then method FilesAdded contents are called but up.start(); never upload file to server. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Dummy me,

Code is ok, IT DOES NOT UPLOAD IF FILE IS NOT **.CSV** extension!